# How to coordinate the dividends and PAYE in United Kingdom

Tags: united-kingdom

I have an IT contracting company. Just registered for PAYE. How much salary should I get and how do we give dividends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone who is an employee needs to get a salary that is at least the national minimum wage.

Anyone who is a director need not be paid but you may find HMRC taking a special interest in you if you are doing work for the company but not earning a realistic salary.

Anyone who is a registered shareholder in a limited company will receive dividends (if any) in proportion to their shareholding. There are complications if you have several classes of shares. Dividends are usually payable from any remaining profit left after all operating costs, salaries and taxes, have been accounted for. Dividends can also be paid from retained profits but it is wise to make sure your business is operating in accordance with industry norms.

The owners of a limited company can decide how to allocate money between salaries and dividends but the tax treatment has been changed to reduce many of the tax advantages that were previously associated with dividends. The main effect is likely on national insurance (NI) payments. Not paying NI now can of course have negative consequences later in life.

Dividends have to be approved by a meeting of shareholders and minuted. They can be paid at whatever intervals the owners wish, so long as there are funds to pay the dividend.

The mechanics of payments are the same (writing a cheque, making a bank transfer, etc) but obviously have to be accounted for separately, consistently and correctly. PAYE is a big subject, one I can't cover.

You also need to understand [IR35](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/ir35-find-out-if-it-applies) thoroughly, since you "have an IT contracting company".

In short: consult a good chartered accountant (not just a bookkeeper who calls themselves an accountant).

Comment: If as a director you also work for the company then you do have to be paid for that work.

Comment: @Vicky: Point taken (I think)